Big query self join
I am experiencing a very weird behaviour with big query I want to self join a table as seen below. This snippet is part of a larger chain of WITH statements.
trigger_recos AS (
     SELECT
         T.session_id trigger_session
        ,T.epoch trigger_epoch
        ,T.categoryId trigger_categoryId
        ,T.refinements_str trigger_refinements_str
        ,R.session_id reco_session
        ,R.epoch reco_epoch
        ,R.categoryId reco_categoryId
        ,R.refinements_str reco_refinements_str
     FROM filtered T
     JOIN filtered R
     ON T.session_id = R.session_id
 )
SELECT * from trigger_recos;

This self join returns nothing but if you go to the previous step and do a:
SELECT * from filtered;
And use the temporary dataset that big query provides and do the join there then this works fine.
Tried the temporary dataset and that works fine but it is not a solution for me as I want to continue the chain of subqueries to get what I eventually work. This sql code will be executed within a spring boot application and the eventually result will end up in a redis instance.

For your self join, every row will match itself. You need another column to exclude the same row match.

A [mcve] would make this much clearer. Make it easy to assist you!

@jarlh I cannot share more of this chain, it is will expose sensitive information. The core of the issue is that the self join here works fine if applied to an actual dataset but it does not work in the chain of "WITH" statements.

I doubt your self join works as desired, since each row will match itself. Show us some made up, fake data and the desired self join result.

It does work as desired when run as I pointed out it does not run as part of a with statement.

Then show us some sample table data and the current, desired result.

Can you please describe what you're trying to acheive ? Make a join on the same table with the same primary key ? You need another discriminant here.
